# Can I convert a BootCamp Windows installation for UEFI booting?

Tags: macos, boot, windows-10, uefi

I had a MacBook Pro 13" 2012 model. It was configured to dual-boot with a BootCamp Windows 10. Recently I moved the stock 500 GB HDD to the optical bay and Windows wouldn't boot anymore, as was mentioned in my previous question here: [On dual-boot MacBook using BootCamp, moved HDD to optical bay and Windows no longer boots](https://superuser.com/questions/1005887/on-dual-boot-macbook-using-bootcamp-moved-hdd-to-optical-bay-and-windows-no-lon).

Now I am thinking of converting the Windows installation into UEFI booting, because I think Windows 10 supports that. I refered to this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/3dlu2g/convert_a_bootcamp_bios_windows_installation_to/, which basically removed the hybrid MBR, created a GPT Microsoft Reserverd (MSR) Partition. However I failed to run `bcdboot` to copy boot files to the EFI partition, which was the last step in the tutorial. As far as I can see, I cannot access (read) any file under `C:\Windows\Boot` or `C:\Windows\System32` when I boot from my Windows PE USB drive. (Where `C:` is the letter of my Windows 10 installation drive seen in Windows PE.)

Then I tried to copy files under `C:\Windows\Boot\EFI` to my flash drive first, in Mac OS X, and then in Windows PE, copy them to the `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot` directory. I also created a BCD file under `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot` and corrected corresponding entries including partition ID and boot file (with extension `.efi`).

However I still cannot see `Windows` at startup when I press and hold `option`. I can only see `Macintosh HD` and `Recovery`, and my flash drive items (if flash drive is present). I am wondering how I can boot back into Windows with UEFI...

In Mac OS X's "Startup Disk" settings I can see both systems. However I am not sure if "Windows" is the correct UEFI boot entry (probably not because it is not in the startup menu) or just an old BootCamp option which was not deleted when simply removing hybrid MBR.

Comment: You may want to refer to [this blog post,](http://sdnalloh.com/converting-win7-from-mbr-to-gpt/) which describes a BIOS-to-UEFI boot-mode conversion on a standard UEFI-based PC. There will be some Mac-specific wrinkles (like the hybrid MBR), but something roughly like the procedure in that blog post should work. Good luck!

Comment: I am afraid that I may not be able to test it out, because I finally wiped Windows and moved (backed-up and recovered) OS X to my SSD... Hope this post would be helpful to whoever find this question is the future.